# ios :check if user submitted review

Tags: ios, itunes-app, appirater

Is it possible to check if a user really submitted the review on the app store. I am redirecting the user to my application's page on the store but I couldn't check if he really submitted the review or not. 
    I am using appirater by arashpayan it allow me to track if the user pressed on the rate button but no actually action is taken if the user submits or not the review.

Comment: I know but the post is a bit old i was hoping for a new answer @Azat

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot track any actions taken outside of your app. This includes that you cannot track whether the user actually submitted a review or not.